# Ubuntu 18.04 does not shut down on ThinkPad T480s. [Errors: "ruc_sched detected stalls" + "hard LOCKUP on CPU"]

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, lockup

I bought a new T480s with preinstalled Win 10. I installed the windows updates (including bios and firmware updates) and then installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 (kernel 4.18.0-15-generic). I am unable to shutdown Ubuntu, as the screen freezes on 'hard LOCKUP on CPU 4'.

I tried the general suggestions to tweak GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT parameter. I have i5-8250u and MX150(although I have not installed the GPU drivers. Currently using Intel UHD.

Many times the device does not boot after force shutdown, and I have to reset it by using the pinhole reset button. First I thought there might be some hardware problem, but there are no issues in Windows. I also tried to use Kubuntu 18.04 but the same problems occurs What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Updating the Linux kernel to 5.2 solved the problem.